# Why is pip unavailable when I install virtualenv?

Tags: python

The documentation says that if I already have virtualenv installed, then pip is available by default on my system. However, there exists `/usr/bin/virtualenv` but no `/usr/bin/pip`. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be `/usr/bin/pip`. pip is installed within your virtualenv. It'll be in the `bin` directory within the virtualenv folder, which is added to the front of your path when you activate the environment.